# How to merge tiles created by "tiledLayout" in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

In MATLAB when working with `subplot` I can merge axes from different subplots to create a larger subplot like:

```
x = 1:10;
figure
subplot(131)
plot(x)
subplot(1,3,2:3)
plot(x+2)
```

Now that MATLAB has introduced `tiledlayout`, I am using it instead of `subplot` as it allows the user to modify the gap between various axes in a figure. But I cannot figure out how I can merge different tiles to create a larger tile. Is there any way I can combine different tiles created by `tiledlayout` to create a larger tile (basically, I am looking for the equivalent of `subplot(1,3,2:3)`)?

Comment: I didn't know you could do that with `subplot`! +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [`nexttile`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nexttile.html) and the various ways to call it. Take for example the documentation of [`nexttile(span)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nexttile.html#mw_532c8b2a-58a1-4e2d-93cd-a52bbab8df70) which says:

> Tile span, specified as a vector of the form `[r c]`, where `r` and `c` are positive whole numbers. Use this argument to make the axes span `r` rows by `c` columns of tiles in the layout.

and the following demonstration is shown:

[image]